# JQuery addClass Function Within addClass Function

Tags: jquery, chaining

On click h1 turns green, but the h2 doesn't turn red. Syntax is correct as far as I can tell, so not sure why.

CSS:

```
.red 
{
    color:red;
}

.green 
{
    color:green;
}
```

jQuery:

```
 $("h1").click(function(){ 

      $("h1").addClass("green", function(){

        $("h2").addClass("red");

      });
    });
```

Comment: is `h2` a child of `h1`?

Comment: addClass takes either a class name, or a function, not both

Comment: `$("h1").addClass("green", function(){

        $("h2").addClass("red");

      });` doesn't make sense, what are you expecting here? I guess you are confusing jQuery UI addClass() with the jQuery ones method. Including jQuery UI, your code works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/0q81wc61/

Comment: `addClass` is synchronous, it doesn't need a callback, it does however have one, but it's not for that use

Comment: Thanks, @a-wolff. I'm not sure what I was doing wrong. I should have mentioned that I wanted h1 to execute, then h2. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `addClass1` function takes only one parameter: a class or a function. Do this instead:

```
$("h1").click(function(){ 

  $("h1").addClass("green");
  $("h2").addClass("red");
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Though I should have specified that I want to chain them i.e. h1 change, then h2. Looks like @a-wolff nailed it.